# Dispatching 2 actions upon submitting with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form and I'd like my component to dispatch two actions upon submitting the form: the first is the action that sends the data from all form-fields(which is a built-in function) and the second that updates the status of a user to 'registered'. The problem is that the built-in handleSubmit function doesn't work when I do it the way you can see below and only "toggleRegistrationStatus" function is called. How do I go about dispatching these actions so the data gets sent and the status gets updated at the same time?
My component's code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class RegistrationPage extends React.Component {

    createAgeOptions(from,to) {
        var options = []
        for(var i=from; i < to; i++) {
            options.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
        }
        return options
    }

    handleRegistration(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      const {handleSubmit, toggleRegistrationStatus, registerUser} = this.props
      handleSubmit(registerUser)
      toggleRegistrationStatus()
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="registration">
            <form action="" onSubmit={this.handleRegistration.bind(this)} className="registration__form">
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <Field component="input" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="surname">Surname:</label>
                <Field name="surname" component="input" id="surname" type="text"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
                <Field name="select" component="select" name="" id="age">
                    {this.createAgeOptions(1948,2015)}
                </Field>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
                <Field name="email" component="input" id="email" type="email"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="telephone">Telephone number:</label>
                <Field name="telephone" component="input" id="telephone" type="telephone"/>
              </div>
              <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'registration'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(RegistrationPage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing submit from form element and instead call it when clicking the submit button like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class RegistrationPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleRegistration = this.handleRegistration.bind(this);
    }

    createAgeOptions(from,to) {
        var options = []
        for(var i=from; i < to; i++) {
            options.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
        }
        return options
    } 

    handleRegistration(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      const {toggleRegistrationStatus, registerUser} = this.props
      toggleRegistrationStatus();
      registerUser();
   }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
          <div className="registration">
            <form action="" className="registration__form">
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <Field component="input" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="surname">Surname:</label>
                <Field name="surname" component="input" id="surname" type="text"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
                <Field name="select" component="select" name="" id="age">
                    {this.createAgeOptions(1948,2015)}
                </Field>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
                <Field name="email" component="input" id="email" type="email"/>
              </div>
              <div className="registration__field">
                <label htmlFor="telephone">Telephone number:</label>
                <Field name="telephone" component="input" id="telephone" type="telephone"/>
              </div>
              <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit(this.handleRegistration)}>Submit!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'registration'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(RegistrationPage)
```

Comment: Will this work the way it should if I add validation? I don't want the data to be submitted unless it passes validation, which I wanted to add as soon as i get this problem sorted.

Comment: It should work with validation, as far as I am concerned validation is bounded with `handleSubmit ` function, not with onSubmit attribute. So what is the problem now?

Comment: The problem is that the built-in handleSubmit function still isn't called and it calls only "toggleRegistrationStatus" function upon submitting. Nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating, now it works! Yep, I thought you meant I should  add event handlers on both the form and the button, that's why it didn't work. By the way, in this case there is no need to prevent default behaviour since it's prevented by the handleSubmit function by default.